# Using JWT and Sessions simultaneously in Node JS for Auth Systems

Tags: node.js, api, security, session, jwt

After reading many many articles about JWT and Sessions, I am quite sure that I should not use JWT for session.

However, is there a chance to use JWT and sessions in the same app? If yes, how and if not, what are the alternatives?

I am currently developing a simple auth system in nodeJS which can login and logout users whenever needed. I am using JWT to store relevant info about the users which can be latter used for accessing certain end points.

So after digging I came to know about sessions also and so I am now confused as to how to use both JWT and Sessions to complete my task. I am quite new to all this stuff so feedback and responses are both appreciated

EDIT: After hours of digging, I feel more confused on when to use JWT and when to use sessions. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT part 2: After receiving the private feedback about why the question is closed, I made some changes to the question.

Comment: Hello fellow stackers. The question was closed and after making edits I would like it to reopen. It would be great if you can consider it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the implementation of JWT should be often stacked with a non-cookie session, unless the application is quite simple.

**Some random scenario:**

Assume the following; a web application is using JWT to authenticate and the application enables the admin to mark any client as a non-active client (Blocked) and therefore the client should be prevented from signing-in.

Now the issue lies upon authenticating with JWT; we wouldn't know if this particular client is blocked or not.

To work around this issue I've seen some devs query the DB on every request. Other devs revoke the JWT and issue a new one flagged as non-active but what if there were too many dynamic flags?. Also hitting the DB this hard is not smart.

**Conclusion JWT + session:**

A simple solution would be granting an in-memory session for each valid JWT and store the user necessary data in it, any change to the user data should get reflected in the user stored session. All incoming requests would get JWT verified as well as session verifying.

Comment: I agree with your inputs. Also, I don't want to hit db calls as it might affect the performance in large scale deployment. My one concern is that even if the session is closed, the jwt token is still authorized and can be used again. Is this the right concern or am I missing something?

Comment: @Hackeerrrr Yes. But consider configuring both the session and the token to have the same TTL/Expiry, both will then expire at the same moment.

Comment: Correct, but if both token and session expire while the user is active, s/he would have to login again and if both are long enough, some attacker can use the info to impersonate the user

Comment: @Hackeerrrr Right. However, refresh tokens come handy in such situations; replace JWT with a new one and refresh the session TTL.

Comment: I agree with your inputs and am consider using them and seeing how they work. Thank you for the responses

Comment: @Hackeerrrr Most welcome, don't forget to feedback the results as well as accepting the answer so others can re-use the solution.